# How can Redis sort according to two different sorted sets?

Tags: redis, sortedset

I have two different sorted sets.

One is for editor ID:

```
article_id  editor_id
101         10
102         11
103         10
104         10
```

The other sorted set is for date sorting:

```
article_id  day
101         29
102         27
103         25
104         27
```

I want to merge these sets which shows first editor second day sorted state.
Which commands should I use?

Comment: Redis Sorted Sets are collections of strings each one associated to a score. What part of your data are the key, the value and the score?

Comment: article_id value, editor_id score and key1 and key2 are the key names.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `article_id` is your members' value and that `editor_id`/`day` are the scores in the respective Sorted Set, and assuming each `article_id` is present in **both** Sorted Sets, you can do the following:

```
ZINTERSTORE t 2 k1 k2 WEIGHTS 100 1 AGGREGATE SUM
```

Explanation:

- `t` is a temporary key that will hold the result
- `k1` is the Sorted Set that stores the `editor_id`
- `k2` is the Sorted Set that stores the `day`
- the weight 100 multiplies `editor_id` by 100 (i.e. "shifts" it two places to the right)
- the `AGGREGATE SUM` results in the following score: `editor_id` * 100 + `day`

Notes:

- you can use `ZUNIONSTORE` instead for the same result
- the use of weight 100 assumes that `day` is a 2-digit value