# In Redis, is it possible to sort a member across multiple Sorted Sets?

Tags: redis

I'm tracking members in multiple Sorted Sets in Redis as a way to do multi-column indexing on the members. As an example, let's say I have two Sorted Sets, `lastseen` (which is epoch time) and `points`, and I store usernames as members in these Sorted Sets.

I'm wanting to first sort by `lastseen` so I can get the users seen within the last day or month, then I'm wanting to sort the resulting members by `points` so I effectively have the members seen within the last day or month sorted by points.

This would be easy if I could store the result of a call to ZREVRANGEBYSCORE to a new Sorted Set (we'll call the new Sorted Set `temp`), because then I could sort `lastseen` with limits, store the result to `temp`, use ZINTERSTORE against `temp` and `points` with a weight of zero for `out` (stored to `result`), and finally use ZREVRANGEBYSCORE again on `result`. However, there's no built-in way in Redis to store the result of ZRANGE to a new Sorted Set.

I looked into using the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29287772/451664), and while it does seem to order the results correctly, the resulting scores in the Sorted Set can no longer be used to accurately limit results based on time (ie. only want ones within the last day).

For example:

```
redis> ZADD lastseen 12345 "foo"
redis> ZADD lastseen 12350 "bar"
redis> ZADD lastseen 12355 "sucka"
redis> ZADD points 5 "foo"
redis> ZADD points 3 "bar"
redis> ZADD points 9 "sucka"
```

What I'd like to end up with, assuming my time window is between `12349` and `12356`, is the list of members `['sucka', 'bar']`.

Comment: I'm not storing historical data in Redis. For example, I'm not storing every time a user has been seen, just the last time. Meaning, each time the member logs in I update the lastseen Sorted set with the username as the member and the current epoch time as the score.

Comment: What I meant was, I'm not storing time-series data in Redis, only the most recent. And yes, the Sorted Sets get populated from PostgreSQL on start-up, but I'd rather query Redis than PostgreSQL in real-time. Regardless, it doesn't really change my question -- I could just as easily used a different example that presented the same use-case.

Comment: I already have that in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions I can think of are:

1) Your wish was to `ZREVRANGEBYSCORE` and somehow save the temporary result. Instead you could copy the zset (which can be done with a `ZINTERSTORE` with only one set as an argument), then do a `ZREMRANGEBYSCORE` on the new copy to get rid of the times you're not interested in, then do the final `ZINTERSTORE`.

2) Do it in a loop on the client, as Eli suggested.

3) Do the same thing in a Lua script.

These are all potentially expensive operations, so what's going to work best will depend on your data and use case. Without knowing more, I would personally lean towards the Lua solution.

Comment: Regarding 1) unless I'm missing something, making a copy with ZINTERSTORE doesn't help since the ZREVRANGEBYSCORE on the copy still won't give me results in a way I can use for the final ZINTERSTORE. Regarding 2) for my use case I have to weight the points score by 1E10, then sum it with the lastseen score for the results to order correctly, which really throws the scores out of whack for limiting based on time.

Comment: @Bryan: 1) `REM`, not `REV`. You're *removing* everything from the copy that's not in your desired time range. 2) I see now. The question you linked to is doing a different kind of sort, with the second column breaking ties on the first. Whereas you just want to use time as a filter, but base the sort entirely on the points. So that approach is not going to work.

Comment: Oh dang, I don't see how I missed the fact that the ZREM* commands even existed! I thought it was a typo on your part.  I'll try it out tomorrow and post back here.

Comment: This indeed worked... I'm marking it as the accepted answer since my original question was about getting this done in Redis. While technically doing it with Lua would constitute getting it done in Redis as well, this method doesn't require anything additional to be done. Whether or not it's a faster or slower solution is a different story... one that I haven't tested yet.

Comment: @Bryan: Happy to help. Regarding performance, I think it's a question of whether the (presumably) faster native operations (compared to Lua) compensate for the extra data shuffling that it requires. I don't think it's possible to say without benchmarking.

Answer (score 1):

For queries that get this complex, you want to supplement Redis' built-in commands with another processing language. The easiest way to do that is calling from within whatever your backend language is and using that to process. An example in Python using [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) is:

```python
import redis
finish_time, start_time = 12356, 12349
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0, password='some_pass')
entries_in_time_frame = r.zrevrangebyscore('lastseen', finish_time, start_time)
p = r.pipeline()
for entry in entries_in_time_frame:
    p.zscore('points', entry)
scores = zip(entries_in_time_frame, p.execute())
sorted_entries = [tup[0] for tup in sorted(scores, key=lambda tup: tup[1])]


>>> ['sucka', 'bar']
```

Note the pipeline, so we're only ever sending two calls to the Redis server, so network latency shouldn't slow us down much. If you need to go even faster (perhaps if what's returned by the first `ZREVRANGEBYSCORE` is very long), you can rewrite the same logic as above [as a Lua script](https://www.redisgreen.net/blog/intro-to-lua-for-redis-programmers/). Here's a working example (note my lua is rusty, so this can be optimized):

```
local start_time = ARGV[1]
local finish_time = ARGV[2]
local entries_in_time_frame = redis.call('ZREVRANGEBYSCORE', KEYS[1], finish_time, start_time)

local sort_function = function (k0, k1)
   local s0 = redis.call('ZSCORE', KEYS[2], k0)
   local s1 = redis.call('ZSCORE', KEYS[2], k1)
   return (s0 > s1)
end

table.sort(entries_in_time_frame, sort_function)

return entries_in_time_frame
```

You can call it like so:

```
redis-cli -a some_pass EVAL "$(cat script.lua)" 2 lastseen points 12349 12356
```

Returning:

```
1) "bar"
2) "foo"
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... not a problem, just curious if it could be done in Redis directly.

Comment: @Bryan mind sharing why you'd prefer that to a lua script?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily prefer it over a Lua script, was just curious if it could be done without. Me saying "afraid" was a bit misleading. 

Comment: I've never used Lua in Redis before. Without doing the work for me, any hints on how to get started with a Lua script for this particular use case, beyond what's in the link you provided?